# Angular2 http.get in interval 1s don't refresh view

Tags: angular

I have a simple model of the angular 2. I have the function that html.get is performed every second , but the variable placed in the view does not refresh itself . What is the problem ?

```
constructor(private _cm: Communication) {}

ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => { 
        this.getDeviceData();
        this.numCountChange.next(this.responseDate)
    }, 1000);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.requestInterval);
}

getDeviceData() {
    this._cm.devicesService.getAccessPointStateByIdDeviceAndIdAccessPoint(10018, 10154)
            .subscribe(
                accessPoint => {
                    this.device0 = accessPoint;
                    this.device0.stateChecker();
                    this.responseDate = new Date()
                    console.log(this.responseDate);
                },
                error => console.log(error)
            );
}
```

html:

```
                    < div class="small-box-footer">
                        {{ responseDate }}
                    < /div>
```

responseDate shows all the time the first response value

Answer (score 1):

It should work without manually invoking change detection but I don't know what for example `devicesService.getAccessPointStateByIdDeviceAndIdAccessPoint` is actually doing and how the code looks like.

This should at least work around it:

```
constructor(private _cm: Communication, private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => { 
        this.getDeviceData();
        this.numCountChange.next(this.responseDate)
    }, 1000);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.requestInterval);
}

getDeviceData() {
    this._cm.devicesService.getAccessPointStateByIdDeviceAndIdAccessPoint(10018, 10154)
            .subscribe(
                accessPoint => {
                    this.device0 = accessPoint;
                    this.device0.stateChecker();
                    this.responseDate = new Date()
                    console.log(this.responseDate);
                    this.cdRef.detectChanges()
                },
                error => console.log(error)
            );
}
```

Comment: This solution works , but when I get the link to view another error occurs

EXCEPTION: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges

Comment: Thats a tricky exception. Can you please try to store the return value of `subscribe` to a class property (for example `subscription`) like `this.subscription = this._cm.deviceService.getAccessPoint ... subscribe()`and in `ngOnDestroy()` call `this.subscription.unsubscribe()`?